# How to print 20 random numbers?

Tags: c#

I am looking to print 20 random numbers. Is it possible to do this with a `for` loop; and if it is, how can I do it?

Here is my current code:

```
    int[] randomNum = new int[20];
    Random RandomNumber = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        randomNum[i] = RandomNumber.Next(1, 80);

    }


    foreach (int j in randomNum)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("First Number:{0}", j);
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your code?

Comment: and how were you not able to google that?

Comment: Oooo sorry for that, the question is how to avoid dublicating of the numbers

Answer (score 2):

Just loop the number generation until it generated a new number:

```
int[] randomNum = new int[20];
Random RandomNumber = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int number;
    do
    {
        number = RandomNumber.Next(1, 80);          
    } while(randomNum.Contains(number));

    randomNum[i] = number;
}

foreach (int j in randomNum)
{
   Console.WriteLine("First Number:{0}", j);
   Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It was very helpful and I am sorry for the asked question  !

Answer (score 1):

According to your last comment, I would say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int num;
    do
    {
         num = RandomNumber.Next(1, 80);
    } while (randomNum.Contains(num));

    randomNum[i] = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you used array for this? If you want to print random numbers, you can write this.

```
       Random RandomNumber = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int randomNum = RandomNumber.Next(1, 80);
            Console.WriteLine("Number:{0}", randomNum);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need in randomNum. Just do it so:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Number:{0}", RandomNumber.Next(1, 80));
    }
```

If you wanna avoid dublication, do so:

```
 List<int> intList = new List();
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
          int r =  RandomNumber.Next(1, 80);
          foreach(int s in intList) if(s!=r){
                intList.Add(s);
                Console.WriteLine("First Number:{0}", RandomNumber.Next(1, 80));
            }else i--;
   }
```

Comment: this is terrible code mate. who can read this? merging multiple commands into one line doesn't make code better and naming variables as short as possible neither.

Comment: very ugly piece of code.